# MySQL results for count of same field value in a grouped query

Tags: mysql, sql

Kind of hard to explain in words, but I am trying to get data grouped by a type and joined by another table to get results.

Here is my [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4af11/6) example.

Here is an example data:

(link table) [id, type, created]

```
(1, 1, '2013-01-01')
(2, 1, '2013-01-02')
(3, 2, '2013-01-03')
(4, 4, '2013-01-04')
```

(info table) [id, link_id, info_type, tally, tick]

```
(1, 1,1,10,15)
(1, 2,2,20,17)
(1, 3,1,12,14)
(1, 4,2,18,21)
```

The results I desire are: [type_a, type_b, tally, tick]

```
(1, 1, 30, 32)
(1, 0, 12, 14)
(0, 1, 18, 21)
```

The results I am getting

```
(2, 2, 30, 32)
(1, 1, 12, 14)
(1, 1, 18, 21)
```

Here is my query I am using

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(i.info_type) as type_a,
    COUNT(i.info_type) as type_b,
    SUM(i.tally) as tally,
    SUM(i.tick) as tick
FROM link l
JOIN info i ON (l.id = i.link_id)
WHERE l.created BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY l.type
```

To sum it I want to get all links in a date range, grouping by link.type
then returning the count of info_type that equals 1 as type_a and equals 2 as type_b
and the sum of tally and tick which is correct. It is just the type_a and type_b results
that are wrong.

Comment: The data in the `link` table are only 2 columns while your description has 3.

Comment: Ill make those corrections I see I might have made a mistake and missing a few fields. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Fixed that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(i.info_type = 1) AS type_a,
    SUM(i.info_type = 2) AS type_b,
    SUM(i.tally) AS tally,
    SUM(i.tick) AS tick
FROM link l
JOIN info i ON l.id = i.link_id
WHERE l.created BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY l.type ;
```

The `SUM(i.info_type = 1)` is a MySQL idiom. The more readable SQL code would be:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN i.info_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS type_a,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN i.info_type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS type_b,
    SUM(i.tally) AS tally,
    SUM(i.tick) AS tick
FROM link l
JOIN info i ON l.id = i.link_id
WHERE l.created BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY l.type ;
```

---

On another note, I don't think you should use `BETWEEN` with dates. The condition as it is will include a whole year plus one day which I doubt can be useful. You can use instead:

```
WHERE l.created >= '2013-01-01' 
  AND l.created < '2014-01-01'    -- notice the missing equal sign here
```

which will result in an interval of exactly one year, no matter if the `created` column is of type `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this what you need

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOD(I.INFO_TYPE,2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type_B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MOD(I.INFO_TYPE,2) <> 0 AND MOD(I.INFO_TYPE, 1) = 0
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type_A,
SUM(I.TALLY) AS TALLY, SUM(I.TICK) AS TICK
FROM link l
JOIN info i ON (l.id = i.link_id)
WHERE l.created BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
GROUP BY L.TYPE
```

Comment: No the type_a and type_b can be 0, 2 and keep counting depending on how many are returned there are no static results.

Comment: As the table grows it can give larger results per line. Since it is grouped by link.type. It just counts how many in that group from info is info_type 1 and 2 so there could be many in the group and type_a and type_b could be 0, 4 if the entry are reflecting such results.

Comment: You need any modifications to the query? If yes, what's the modification you need/